# kladr. Вывести в списке города вместе с регионами

Tags: javascript, jquery, кладр

Код вот такой.

```
$('#city').each(function () {
                            let city_id = $(this).attr('data-default'),
                                $city = $(this);

                            $city.kladr({
                                type: $.kladr.type.city,
                                withParents: true,
                                parentType: $.kladr.type.region,
                                spinner: false
                            });
                            if (demo && city_id && !$(this).val().length) {
                                setTimeout(function () {
                                    $city.kladr('controller').setValueById(city_id);
                                }, 500);
                            }
                        });
```

При наборе выводит названия городов, но мне нужно чтобы вместе с названиями городов выводились и регионы городов в предлагаемом списке. Читал документацию, не понял как можно это сделать.

Comment: я что то не  понял. у вас есть массив элементов с id.??

Comment: @Санитариум Это для заполнения инпута кода города.

Comment: ну просто элеменнты с id  как бы должны быть уникальны

Comment: Просто дефолтное значение

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ здесь
http://savepearlharbor.com/?p=192132 Код правда устаревший чуток

Реализовал так:

```
$city.kladr({
      type: $.kladr.type.city,
      withParents: true,
      labelFormat: function (obj, query) {
                   var result = '';
                   for (var i_c in obj.parents) {
                    result += obj.parents[i_c].typeShort + '. ' + obj.parents[i_c].name + ', ';
                   }
                   result += obj.typeShort + '. ' + obj.name;
                   return result;
                },
                spinner: false
 });
```